# Lucene expression to delete a nested object?

Tags: elasticsearch, groovy

Currently, I am using a Groovy script to delete a nested object:

```
ctx._source.remove(\"nested\")
```

However, the deployment system only allows Lucene expressions. What would be the equivalent of this Groovy script?

Comment: Please see if [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33825029/elasticsearch-deleting-nested-object-using-java-api-not-working) helps.

Comment: @Rao dynamic scripting is enabled but for lucene expressions only.

Comment: wouldn't [source filtering](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-request-source-filtering.html)  work ?