# Add and delete object in nested property ElasticSearch

Tags: php, elasticsearch, elasticsearch-painless

How to delete and add item in nested property in ElasticSearch? most of the examples not working.

Comment: How are they not working? What have you tried? Please consider expanding your question with some examples and add clarity.

Answer (score 1):

A simpler way of removing items (inspired from [my other answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33825029/elasticsearch-deleting-nested-object-using-java-api-not-working/33826878#33826878)).

No for loops, no ifs :-)

```
$this->getClient()->update(
    [
        'index' => $this->getIndexName(),
        'id' => $Item->getReportId(),
        'body' => [
            'script' => [
                'lang' => 'painless',
                'inline' => 'ctx._source.reports.removeAll{ it -> it.entry_id == params.entry_id && it.source == params.source }',
                'params' => ['entry_id' => (string)$Item->getEntryId(), 'source' => $Item->getTableName()],
            ],
        ],
    ]
);
```

Answer (score 0):

I've spent a lot of hours on figuring out how to add new object into nested array in ElasticSearch and how to delete it. There are a llot of answers on StackOverflow but most of them are outdated. So there are examples:

```
    $this->getClient()->update(
        [
            'index' => $this->getIndexName(),
            'id' => $Item->getReportId(),
            'body' => [
                'script' => [
                    'lang' => 'painless',
                    'inline' => 'int idx = -1;
                     for (int i = 0; i < ctx._source.reports.length; ++i) {
                      if (ctx._source.reports[i].entry_id == params.entry_id && ctx._source.reports[i].source == params.source) { 
                       idx=i; 
                      } 
                     } 
                     if (idx != -1)
                      ctx._source.reports.remove(idx);',
                    'params' => ['entry_id' => (string)$Item->getEntryId(), 'source' => $Item->getTableName()],
                ],
            ],
        ]
    );

    $this->getClient()->update(
        [
            'index' => $this->getIndexName(),
            'id' => $Item->getReportId(),
            'body' => [
                'script' => [
                    'lang' => 'painless',
                    'inline' => 'ctx._source.reports.add(params.object)',
                    'params' => ['object' => $entry]
                ],
            ],
        ]
    );
```

Comment: `(string)` conversion here due to `==` cares about types